# Need explanation on "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

Tags: sql-server

How can I get an error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

on line 2 with this code?

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP 
FROM TABLE_X 
WHERE ID = 'd3552bdf-d739-4818-9cf3-f8abba56e7a1'

INSERT INTO TABLE_X 
    SELECT * 
    FROM #TEMP
```

Comment: Please avoid *blind insert.* It is a good practice to always specify  column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TABLE_X` could have an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) or a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) that do not allow inserted values. These columns do output/return a value when using `select *` (*or `select [column name]`*) and would be created in the temp table as a standard column in your `SELECT INTO` statement.

If you want a definitive answer you will have to supply the `DDL` (schema definition) for the table. You can retrieve this using SSMS or using commands like `sp_columns TABLE_X` (there are multiple ways to get schema definitions).

Comment: Thanks. Computed fields were the issue.